# comparing memory addresses of object instances in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, memory-address

In my program, I add an instance of class Laser to a a vector whenever the mouse is clicked. Later, when updating the lasers movement, I check if it has traveled past a certain distance and if it has, I would like to remove it from the vector. So i loop through the vector at first comparing the Lasers positions to the position of this.getPosition(), however it never worked. So instead I tried using operator overloading so I could == the laser in the vector and the 'this' laser. All I want to know is if the laser in the vector is the same as the 'this' laser. but it never works. Here's my code for it.

```
class Laser
{
public:
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    int speed;
    sf::Vector2i startPoint;
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    sf::Sound sound;
    void move(std::vector <Laser> shots);
    bool operator == (const Laser& rh)const; 
    Laser(float rot, int spd, sf::Vector2i pos);
    Laser() {};
    ~Laser();
};
```

and the code for the operator overload and where i actually try and see if its the same laser.

```
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++) {
            if (*this == shots[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index >= 0) {
            shots.erase(shots.begin() + index);
        }


    }

}

bool Laser::operator==(const Laser & rh) const
{
    return (*this == rh);
}
```

so really, all i want to do is compare their memory addresses to see if they are the same instances of laser or not, so i can remove it from a vector. Thanks for any help in advance and sorry if i've been particularly ignorant or rude or anything like that.

Comment: `(*this == rh)` does not compare addresses. In fact this will call `Laser::operator==` recursively and cause a stack overflow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*this` is a `Laser`, and `rh` is a laser, so it calls `Laser::operator==`.
And inside of that `*this` is a `Laser`, and `rh` is a laser, so it calls `Laser::operator==`.
And inside of that `*this` is a `Laser`, and `rh` is a laser, so it calls `Laser::operator==`.
And inside of that `*this` is a `Laser`, and `rh` is a laser, so it calls `Laser::operator==`.

You see the issue? If all you want to do is compare the memory addresses, then do that instead.  `this` is a memory address, and `&rh` is a memory address, so:

```
return this==&rh
```

That being said, this is a terrible idea.  Identity should not be the basis for equality in C++.  If you explain the real problem, we can come up with a far better solution.

Comment: ok, I did try thsi before because i found it in another question, but it never return true, even though it should because all the lasers are in the vector im checking. So is there something wrong with int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++) {
            if (*this == shots[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index >= 0) {
            shots.erase(shots.begin() + index);
        }

Comment: Most likely because the object you're comparing with isn't in the vector.  This code is accurate, it's the code that checks the vector that's incorrect.

Comment: the only way the comparison doesnt come up as a bug is if i dereference this, or make shots[i] a reference, but that doesnt work either.

Comment: @Coned_Stoding: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: okay, well what you've said has given me food for thought. I shall go and try a few tests. Thank you for your help!